# Google-NDK / Compiling command-line C applications without any JNI interaction

Tags: c, android-ndk

Android-NDK is mostly used to write/port native libs which can be called from Java through the JNI mechanism.

I have an ARM based evalboard embedding Android. This evalboard has a serial port so that I can log with a remote terminal on it and then launch commands or other apps ("command line apps" - non Java apps).

I wonder if that is possible with Android NDK to compile "pure" C applications which I will later use as a command on the remote shell? The main idea is to benefit from the toolchain provided by Google-NDK to build code which never interacts with the Dalvik machine.

Best Regards,
Apple92

Comment: In fact, there is a new feature in the latest NDK. You can generate your own toolchain and call it from any Makefile.

Answer (score 4):

[Hello World C program using Android Toolchain](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/hello-world-c-program-on-using-android.html) is an article to explain how to compile using android toolchain. I think it useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compile command line programs using the NDK. If you take a look at any functioning Android system, you'll find many examples of command line programs which have been compiled using that same compiler.

Comment: Do you have links to such examples ?

Comment: Just stumbled across the same problem as user255607, and while this answer is technically right, it's also completely worthless.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz since no problem was asked which could be answered with more detail, I think your comment is on the side of worthless as well. You've been around SO long enough to know that questions must be asked, rather than assumed. The question originally asked was answered. If you feel my answer is useless, please indicate what part of the question I ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is BUILD_EXECUTABLE command, which acts like BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY but produces an executable.
The trick is the libraries your executable depends upon - they will either need to be on device already (/system/bin) or you will have to upload them with your executable.

I came up with the following script to upload and execute tests:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

adb shell rm -r /data/temp
adb shell mkdir /data/temp

for i in dst/* 
do
  adb push ${i} /data/temp
done

cat <<EOF | adb shell
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/temp
/data/temp/test
exit
EOF
```